# selecting and skipping elements

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, linq-to-xml

I am trying to improve some code and I can't think of a better way to do what it currently does. essentially i loop outside for the number of items divided by the number I want to select, then inside that loop I select the item based on an inner loop of the number of items I need to create a single item modifying that by the outerloop value, so in the example below the outer loop loops twice (0,1) and the inner loop twice per outer loop (0,1 then 2,3).

Can anyone see a more readable way to do this or a way to do it without doing the two loops?

Hope that makes sense. Thanks.

Consider XML of

```
string xml = @"
<MainItem>
 <Select>2</Select>
 <ItemArray>
   <Item>One</Item>
   <Item>Two</Item>
   <Item>Three</Item>
   <Item>Four</Item>
 </ItemArray>
</MainItem>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

Here the Select value tells me how many items create one "object" so in this case 2 items are an object (this can be any number but the number of items will always allow for the correct number of objects) currently i am doing somethng like

```
    List<List<XElement>> items = new List<List<XElement>>();
    for(int i = 0;i < (doc.Descendants("Item").Count() / (int)doc.Element("MainItem").Element("Select"));i++)
    {
      //this is one object
     var singleItem = new List<XElement>();
      for (int j = 0; j <  (int)doc.Element("MainItem").Element("Select"); j++)
     {
         var item =  doc.Descendants("Item").ElementAt(j + (i * (int)doc.Element("MainItem").Element("Select")));
         singleItem.Add(item);
     }
     items.Add(singleItem);
    }
```

So we end with a list of List with 2 items, each item holds 2 XElements each (One and Two together and Three and Four together)
so..

```
ItemOne
 One
 Two
ItemTwo
 Three
 Four
```

Comment: You should probably format your XML and show a sample of the XML output you expect.

Comment: @Winston Smith done as requested, thanks for the input

Comment: How many times are you going to recalculate this `(int)doc.Element("MainItem").Element("Select")`?

Comment: how is the grouping made? What if there were 5 items and `Select=2`?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov absolutely right about the recaclculate, that is one area wher i will either remove altogether or calculate once in the finished code, as far as the grouping as I said, due to the way the data is constructed 5 tems select 2 wont happen, it always creates enough items to create an even amount of groups if that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a simple way to do it with a single LINQ statement. You can group by `item index / batchSize`, as follows:

```
int batchSize = (int)doc.Element("MainItem").Element("Select");
var items = doc
            .Descendants("Item")
            .Select( (e, i) => new {i,e} )
            .GroupBy( g => g.i / batchSize )
            .Select( g => g.Select( gv => gv.e) )
            ;
```

This gives an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<XElement>>`, in the structure you describe.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static IEnumerable<List<T>> Batch<T>(
  this IEnumerable<T> source,
  int batchAmount) 
{ 
  List<T> result = new List<T>(); 
  foreach(T t in source) 
  { 
    result.Add(t); 
    if (result.Count == batchSize) 
    { 
      yield return result; 
      result = new List<T>(); 
    } 
  } 
  if (result.Any()) 
  { 
    yield return result; 
  } 
}
```

Called By

```
int batchAmount = (int)doc.Element("MainItem").Element("Select"));

List<List<XElement>> items = doc.Descendants("Item")
  .Batch(batchAmount)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: wish I could accept 2 answers +1 on this it works and achieves what I needed, only difference between yours and the accepted answer is the need for an extension method

Comment: Winston Smith's answer is cool (I've written it before), but slow when used over 10,000 elements.